# What's the status of Esperanto in the Orient, in Asia and in the Far East?

Tags: culture

What's the status of Esperanto in the Orient? Is it at all popular? How many Esperanto speakers are there in Asia? How many in the Far East?

Comment: I dont have a full answer, but here's how its like in japan: JEI reports it have 1150~ members in jan 2017, which is on a down trend. The main problem I personally think is we lack tools like duolingo that allows us to learn easily online, and in general people just dont know about it.

Comment: Here the authors postulate it is even less in china. http://reto.cn/php/hanyu/kiom-da-parolantoj-de-esperanto-en-cinio/

Comment: What do you mean by status? By the way, if you want to ask people directly, there are a lot of Japanese Esperantists on Twitter, and a lot of Iranian Esperantists on Telegram.

Comment: China Radio International still broadcasts in Esperanto: http://esperanto.cri.cn  That would probably be a good location to find out...

Comment: I asked within a chinese esperanto group, and the admin said "nobody is counting". But he has two groups on WeChat, the chinese IMS, with about 600~ish members combined.

Comment: "Status" as in, which organizations are there, what congresses are there and so on, in order to get an overview of what it looks like in Asia. And I really think Asia is a wide enough scope for the question.

Answer (score 6):

There is a lot of information available (in Esperanto) on the page of the [Asian Commission of the Universal Esperanto Association](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azia-Oceania_Komisiono_de_UEA) on Wikipedia.
For example, we can see that between 100 and 600 people attend congresses in Asia. There is also a list of all the national Esperanto associations in Asia, about twenty, each with a Wikipedia page.

The name of the congress in Esperanto is: Azia Kongreso de Esperanto (in English: Asian Esperanto Congress). It takes place every 3 years. The next one is in april 2019 in Vietnam.

Names for the organizations: their name is composed for the most part as follows: name of the country, Esperanto, association. For example: Nepal Esperanto Association (Nepala Esperanto-Asocio), Korea Esperanto Association (Korea Esperanto-Asocio), etc.

Comment: Could you (or someone else) add names for the organizations and/or the congresses? That would be great!

Comment: The name of the congress in Esperanto is: Azia Kongreso de Esperanto (in English: Asian Esperanto Congress). It takes place every 3 years. The next one is in april 2019 in Vietnam.

Comment: Names for the organizations: their name is composed for the most part as follows: name of the country, Esperanto, association. For example: Nepal Esperanto Association (Nepala Esperanto-Asocio), Korea Esperanto Association (Korea Esperanto-Asocio), etc.

Comment: Sed ĉu vi povas ampleksigi vian respondon, bonvolu. Could you add this to your answer?